# How can I create a method that can I use to send string data to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, methods, webview

I have created a simple WebView app with one single WebView fragment.

I have a navigation drawer with 5 to 6 website URLs and what I want is when someone clicks on that particular link that will be open in that WebView.

Any link clicked open that in a single webview fragment.

**I have created this method in MainActivity.java**

```
public void sendData() {

        String[] urls = new String[5];

        urls[0] = getString(R.string.facebook_url);
        urls[1] = getString(R.string.instagram_url);
        urls[2] = getString(R.string.youtube_url);
        urls[3] = getString(R.string.telegram_url);
        urls[4] = getString(R.string.about_url);

        Fragment frag = new WebFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString("weburl", urls[0]);
        bundle.putString("weburl", urls[1]);
        bundle.putString("weburl", urls[2]);
        bundle.putString("weburl", urls[3]);
        bundle.putString("weburl", urls[4]);

        frag.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.webContainer, frag).commit();
    }
```

**And this is navigation click**

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

       int id = item.getItemId();

       switch (id) {
           case R.id.fbMenu:
               sendData();
               break;

           case R.id.igMenu:
               sendData();
               break;

           case R.id.ytMenu:
               sendData();
               break;

           case R.id.teleMenu:
               sendData();
               break;

           case R.id.about:
               sendData();
               break;
       }

        return false;
    }
```

**And this is WebView Fragment**

```
webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webViewFragment);

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

        String webUrls = bundle.getString("weburl");
        webView.loadUrl(webUrls);
```

I don't know how to create a method with parameters and all.

Please help

Comment: What do you mean by "method with parameters"? What is the issue you encounter?

Comment: did you see the method sendData();

Comment: I want to send different url to fragment webview with sendData method.

Comment: Can you share webfragment code

Comment: already did, check webview fragment. in webview fragment  I just received the data from bundle.

Answer (score -1):

The method sendData() sets the same URL in this piece of code. Each time you set the "webUrl" with the putString method, it overrides the previous

```
    bundle.putString("weburl", urls[0]);
    bundle.putString("weburl", urls[1]);
    bundle.putString("weburl", urls[2]);
    bundle.putString("weburl", urls[3]);
    bundle.putString("weburl", urls[4]);
```

So the webview will always open the last of the URLs (urls[4]).

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
public void sendData(String url) {
    ...
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("weburl", url);
    ...
}
```

And change the switch to this:

```
 switch (id) {
    case R.id.fbMenu:
        sendData(getString(R.string.facebook_url););
        break;
```

Comment: hey thanks but Can you explain more about fragment lines. because it is not working. I think I am missing something

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? With the code you've shown, the webview fragment should work. You can always follow it with the debugger and check if the line with bundle.getString("weburl") returns the correct url.

Comment: It is working now. Thanks a lot, friend you save my day.

Comment: bundle.putString("weburl", urls[4]); putting same name would replace the value in bundle